# How to resolve fatal error when using namespace in a class

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I have a PHP class that I would like to add a namespace to it.
I am using `PHP Version 5.5.12` on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Apache 2.4

My Permissions class in located in `/classes/Permissions.php`

```
class Permissions
{
     private $db;

     public function __construct(){

     }

     public function sayHello(){
         echo 'Hello';
     }

     private function _test(){

     }

}
?>
```

When I want to start a new instance of the class, I do this in a file located `"/test.php"`

```
require_once 'classes/Permissions.php';
$r = new Permissions();
$r->sayHello();
```

And this is working fine.

Now I am trying to add namespace "which I never used before"

I changed my code to implement namespace like so

```
<?php
namespace classes\Permissions;
class Permissions
{
     private $db;

     public function __construct(){

     }

     public function sayHello(){
         echo 'Hello';
     }

     private function _test(){

     }

}
?>
```

and when staring a new instance of the class I do this

```
require_once 'classes/Permissions.php';
$r = new classes\Permissions();
$r->sayHello();
```

But with this I get a fatal error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Permissions' not found
```

What am I doing wrong? and how to correct it?

Comment: Try `namespace \classes\Permissions;` then `$r = new Permissions();`

Comment: I tried this also but it did not work

Comment: If you don't have a "folder" called Permissions, then that could be it; you're using a filename. Try just `namespace \classes;`

Comment: I do not have a folder called Permissions. Permissions is the name of the PHP file. I only have a folder called "classes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to require the file manually with `require_once` you're free to put the class under any namespace you like. So you can go:

```
namespace Foo;

class Permissions {}
```

You can instantiate this class with:

```
require_once 'path.to.classfile.php';

$r = Foo\Permissions(); //if you're in global namespace
```

docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

So when you have a class like this:

```
namespace classes\Permissions;

class Permissions {}
```

The way to create an object after you include it is with `new classes\Permissions\Permissions();` again assuming you're in global namespace.

Comment: does this mean if I use `new classes\Permissions\Permissions();` I will not need require_once?

Comment: If you have an autoloader set up yes.

Comment: Thank you. and autoloader is just a class that class other classes and get the ready for use?

Answer (score 0):

You should call classes with backslash at begin of namespace.
Try like this:

```
$r = new \classes\Permissions();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not it `\classes\Permissions\Permissions()`? You have a class `Permissions` in `\classes\Permissions` namespace